Making a Laravel App Accessible on Local Network with Dynamic IPv4 in Ubuntu 22
I'm familiar with exposing a Laravel application on the local network using the --host and --port flags. However, my goal is to allow other users on the same network to access it using a local DNS. The challenge I'm facing is that my IPv4 address keeps changing, so I can't rely on setting up a cronjob to run php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.1 --port=8080 on reboot. I need a solution that ensures accessibility for other users on the local network even when the IPv4 address changes dynamically. Any suggestions or strategies to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried static IP configurations. but i couldn't setup
